# Building LSTM model in pytorch equivalent to another one in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, lstm

I have a model in TensorFlow that I converted to Pytorch. I want to check If the two models are the same or if I'm mixing things up. Here is my code in tensofrlow:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(
   LSTM(5, input_shape=(4, 1000))
)
model.add(
    Dense(1, activation='tanh')
)
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(
    X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=27
)
```

I built the equivalent model in Pytorch in this way:

```
class LSTM1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, seq_length):
        super(LSTM1, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes #number of classes
        self.num_layers = num_layers #number of layers
        self.input_size = input_size #input size
        self.seq_length = seq_length #sequence length
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size #hidden state

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size,
                          num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True) #lstm
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, num_classes) #fully connected last layer

        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self,x):
        h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) #hidden state
        c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) #internal state
        # Propagate input through LSTM
        output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0)) #lstm with input, hidden, and internal state
        hn = hn.view(-1, self.hidden_size) #reshaping the data for Dense layer next
        out = self.sigmoid(hn)
        out = self.fc(out) #Final Output
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        return out

num_epochs = 100 #100 epochs
learning_rate = 0.001 #0.001 lr

input_size = 1000 #number of features
num_layers = 5 #number of stacked lstm layers
hidden_size = 1
num_classes = 1 #number of output classes 

X_train = np.concatenate((X_phage, X_bac))
y_train = np.concatenate((np.ones(len(X_phage)), np.zeros(len(X_bac))))

X_train_tensors_final = Variable(torch.Tensor(X_train))
y_train_tensors = Variable(torch.Tensor(y_train))
print(X_train_tensors_final.shape)

model = LSTM1(num_classes, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, X_train_tensors_final.shape[1]) #our lstm class

print("Training Shape", X_train_tensors_final.shape, y_train_tensors.shape)
print(model)

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    outputs = model.forward(X_train_tensors_final) #forward pass
    optimizer.zero_grad() #caluclate the gradient, manually setting to 0
    
    # obtain the loss function
    outputs = outputs[-20:]
    y_train_tensors = y_train_tensors.type(torch.LongTensor)
    y_train_tensors = torch.reshape(y_train_tensors, (20, 1))
    loss = criterion(outputs, y_train_tensors.float())
    
    loss.backward() #calculates the loss of the loss function
    
    optimizer.step() #improve from loss, i.e backprop
    train_acc = torch.sum((outputs > 0.5).bool().float() == y_train_tensors)
    final_train_acc = train_acc/20

    print("Epoch: %d, loss: %1.5f" % (epoch, loss.item()))
    print('Accuracy: ', final_train_acc)
```

My data is 20 instances, where each instance has 1000 features and 4 timesteps, therefore it is shaped like this (20,4,1000). However, When I run the two models, I got different results (different loss and accuracy). Therefore I'm afraid I have missed something and the models are not the same.
I would appreciate it if someone can validate that these models are the same and if they were then why I'm getting different results?

Comment: Naturally, you would expect slightly different result because of different initializations and not all default values are equal. Is it an error that you use tanh in the keras model and sigmoid in pytorch?

Comment: @Plagon The problem is that there is a big difference. For example, in TensorFlow, the accuracy starts at 0.5 and reaches 1 after a few epochs. While PyTorch finishes the 100 epochs at an accuracy 0.5, I don't know if this can change with bigger data. Regarding the activation function, I changed it to sigmoid to enforce the output to be a probability. It doesn't raise any error but do you think it can change the evaluation results?

Comment: That paints a different picture. When using crossentropy, you should output a probability so a sigmoid is the right choice in this case. Another error is that you set `num_layers=5` in the pytorch LSTM when you meant to put `hidden_size=5`

Comment: You can use [torchinfo](https://pypi.org/project/torchinfo/) to print the architecture in the same way as keras

Comment: @Plagon Thank you so much, I think that was it. When I changed the hidden size I got similar behavior. I also validated the structure in both and they are similar. Thanks for your answer.